# Make forms show once a previous one is completed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering if it is possible using angular, to fill forms (inputs) out in an order, but let them build on each other (don't show all at first). For my example (still trying to learn angular) can the user select something from a dropdown, then that will cause an input field to appear, then once that one is filled it will make another appear? I think this would be done through `ng-show` but I am not sure. I have a plunker I was trying it on but haven't gotten it to work yet. [Plunker here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/SgflionwhmqXq4bbfaTi?p=preview)

This is the body of the plunker here. You can see the select, and 2 input fields:

```
<body ng-app="timeExample">
  <select id="type" ng-model="type">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Type</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
  </select>
<script>
  angular.module('numberExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.example = {
        value: 12
      };
    }]);
</script>
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>Number:
    <input type="number" name="input" ng-model="example.value"
           min="0" max="99" required>
 </label>
  <div role="alert">
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
      Required!</span>
    <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.number">
      Not valid number!</span>
  </div>
  <tt>value = {{example.value}}</tt><br/>

 </form>

  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="DateController as dateCtrl">
    <input type="time" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="example.value" placeholder="HH:mm:ss" required />
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
         Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.time">
         Not a valid date!</span>
    </div>
    <tt>value = {{example.value | date: "HH:mm:ss"}}</tt>
    <br/>

  </form>
    <script>
    angular.module('timeExample', [])
      .controller('DateController', ['$scope',
        function($scope) {
          $scope.example = {
            value: new Date(1970, 0, 1, 14, 57, 0)
          };
        }
      ]);
  </script>
</body>
```

Also I didn't really know what to do with the scripts. Can I just put those in the js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can!

Just use an `ng-show` (good thinking) to see that both inputs are filled (using `ng-model`). [Here is a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/a33xftd0/).

As for your second question, you can and should put them in `.js` files, and include them in your `index.html`.